# How to change Currency symbol(₹) color to green in magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]

**I have tried with css first selector but its not wotking ,any solutions from customization**

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS(Product Detail Page-PDP):**

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.price:first-letter {
    color: beige;
}
```